# How to make a frequency histogram in java

Tags: java, histogram, frequency

I am trying to create a code that reads through a file and prints out the following:

- number of lines of the file
- the frequency of each letter
- the frequency of each non-alphabetic character

I want to create a histogram for the frequency of the letters and numbers but I can't seem to find a solution around it. If anything i would want the output to look like this:

```
A ***** - 5
B *** - 3
C ******* - 7
```

My output looks like this:

```
*********************
*********************
*********************
A 263
B 130
C 50
```

etc.

Comment: What do the contents of your file look like? I'd be able to help you if I knew what you are trying to read from.

Comment: It is just a file with many paragraphs of information - imagine copying and pasting a couple paragraphs from a Wikipedia page

Comment: Ohhh. I misread it. Now I get it. You are trying to read the number of letters. What problems are you running into?

Comment: and what does not work? You could use Java 8 stream API and look for the word count example. It's just one more step to flat map each word to the characters and then get the character count

Comment: @Ishaan I can't print it in the format i want to, It's printing all the stars at the top of the page and then prints the array of letters with the corresponding numbers.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks for the suggestion but I'm hoping to create it purely on Java

Comment: Don't print the stars while looping throught the charracters of the file. Print them at the end, after the loop, when you print the number of occurrences of each character.

Comment: ehm, my suggestion was to use Java 8 streams. Where did I suggest to use not Java?

Comment: @masterandomguy, welcome to stack overflow! It looks like this may be a homework problem. There's nothing wrong with asking homework problems, but do read this about homework questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do the task. It counts the number of lower case letters and prints the stars as well in addition to the frequency, just as you wanted.

Here is the general code (`paragraph` is the string that contains the content of your file):

```
int[] lettercount = new int[26];
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    //Set every single number in the array to 0.
    lettercount[i] = 0;
}

for(char s : paragraph.toCharArray()){
    int converted = (int) s;
    converted -= 97;
    if(converted >=0 && converted <=25){
        lettercount[converted] += 1;
    }
}

//Print out the letter with the frequencies.
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    char convertback = (char) (i+97);
    String stars = "";
    for(int j = 0; j < lettercount[i]; j++){
        stars += "*";
    }
    System.out.println(convertback + " " + stars + " - " + lettercount[i]);
}
```

This should work for lowercase letters. If you want to do uppercase letters, `lettercount[]` should be 52 elements long. You would also have to check if `converted` *(in the second for loop)*, after subtracting 97 is negative, and if it is, you would add back 58.

I hope this helps! If you have any problems, just comment below.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did a little bit of modifying and it worked, much appreciated!

Comment: You are most welcome! If you found this answer useful, please upvote it or accept it as an answer therefore others can refer to it if they face similar issues.

Comment: Thank you and I am glad that I was able to help you!

Comment: A few things. First, this looks an awful lot like a homework problem, and I'd encourage @masterandomguy to do his own work. Second, this solution relies on specifics of how characters are assigned numbers (the `- 97` bit) and really isn't a very good demonstration. It doesn't handle non-latin characters at all, é, for example, won't be counted correctly.  I would suggest using a `Map` instead, and maybe a set of default characters that you want reported.

Comment: Yes, as Yona said I was initially thinking of using a map with a Character key and an Integer value. The way that this would work is you would get the character and check if there is a pair in your map that has the same key. If not, you would add the Character and the value of 1. If the pair did exist, you would get the value associated with that character, increment it, and then add it back to the map.     
For your purposes, counting English letters, I think the current solution is sufficient. Maps would be useful if you wanted to count non- English letters such as á or symbols like '!'.